# Facebook format date to specified format in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, date, datetime

I am trying to work with Nativia.io
But as datetime they are asking to be in that format : YYYYMMDDThhmmss

I tried to execute this code :

```
$facebookDate = strtotime("2018-06-28T19:00:00+0200";
date('YYYYMMDDThhmmss', $facebookDate);
```

But that's didn't work as expected.
I'm getting as answer : 2018201820182018JunJunThuThuGMT+0200070706060000

So i tried : `date('YmdThs', $facebookDate);`
The result is : 20180628UTC0500

And i would love to have : 20180628T190000

I know that it's simple but i don't get it.

Comment: @Philipp It should be capital `H`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Simply try the following pattern, `Ymd\THis`, Like:

```
date('Ymd\THis', $facebookDate);
```

In date format `m` is for month and `i` is for minutes.

Comment: Thank you! How can i set the timezone on date function?

Comment: Just use something like `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');`